# paid for a month and left after 2 days

Tags: united-kingdom

I started a new job a few weeks back only worked 2 days then left the job wasn't described as it was to me in the interview. So I went back to my previous job then today I got a payslip paying me for a full month when I only was there for 2 days. Legally what could I do. Morally I don't care

Comment: Sorry, asking for legal advice, outwith the scope of this site, voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

There're plenty of stories in the news about people who ended up getting money in their bank account due to an error by someone else being jailed after going on a shopping spree.  Unless you want 15 minutes of shame, you need to contact the company to fix the mistake.

Comment: Correct.  Also, ensure that you have sufficient funds in your account for the "Correction," if it was direct deposit.  (Didn't know if "Pay Slip" was the deposit summary or a check - sorry, UK:  "cheque")  :)  Good answer, but have to VTC the question - legal advice.